# Issues with linking activities through textview on Android studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Good day Am having issues with my app on Android studio I am new to Android studio tho but I succeeded in creating an app but anytime I click on my edittext to link me to the next activity the app close automatically without any prompt of the cause of the error and I use the right ID for my onclicklistener and and I included the right start activity and Target activity on my intent in my java

Comment: plesase provide code about your problem, such as when you start activity and click event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.